# Addition Symbol Isn't showing In PDF

Tags: equations, symbols, pdf

i'm new to LaTex and am struggling with getting the addition symbol to show on the PDF.

In other equations, this symbol is showing perfectly, but this one is different.

I've tried all the relevant Math Packages and still, nothing is working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
      \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
           \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[] F = Frequency
            \item[] C = speed of sound (344 meters per second)
            \item[] L = Length of Room
            \item[] W = Width of Room
            \item[] H = Height of Room
        \end{itemize}
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} 
        F = C/2 $\cdot$ 
        $\sqrt{((P^2 / L^2)  + (Q^2  / W^2)  +  (R^2  / H^2))}$
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If you mean the `$\cdot$`, it shows up fine.  BTW, your text is protruding slightly out of the text area.  Add a `%` immediately after the first `\end{minipage}` to prevent adding an extra space.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Cheers man, but i actually meant the + sign!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All plus signs show up. If they do not your document, this must have to do with your document preamble, which you did not disclose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
      \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
           \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[] F = Frequency
            \item[] C = speed of sound (344 meters per second)
            \item[] L = Length of Room
            \item[] W = Width of Room
            \item[] H = Height of Room
        \end{itemize}
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright} 
        F = C/2 $\cdot$ 
        $\sqrt{((P^2 / L^2)  + (Q^2  / W^2)  +  (R^2  / H^2))}$
    \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers man, i had an extra font package that was causing the problem. Works dandy